# "Could not find the main class" error

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have a .jar generated by Eclipse, which I cannot run on other computer (with Windows XP). The "Could not find the main class. Program will exit" message appears. That computer runs fine another .jar generated by Netbeans, so it is not a problem with JRE, I guess. I updated JRE but it changed nothing. What is the problem?

UPDATE: I forgot to mention, that I made a runnable jar file. On two another computers it works fine (win 7 and XP), but on that specific one not.

UPDATE 2: It's a Swing application, so the JAR is run by double-clicking.

Comment: Are you trying to run a `main` method of a class?

Comment: Yes. I have  a JFrame with main method.

Comment: You are right - I had no time to read about all stuff connected with functionality of stackoverflow and I thought that clicking on a "This answer is useful" do the thing. Good advice for future :)

Comment: Please update the question with the exact clues you have. You said you have a JAR, and that very same JAR is being run on several machines using the very same `java` command-line? Please give us the exact command line that starts your program.

Comment: No command, I just double-click on the JAR. It's a swing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the contents of the manifest.  The `Main-Class: foo.Bar` line must correspond to an /foo/Bar.class entry in the jar file, and `foo.Bar.java` must contain an appropriate main-method.   Also all jars reference in the `Class-Path:` line must be copied too.

Use "jar tvf my.jar" to see the layout.

Comment: But even if there is something wrong with class-path, how is it possible that it runs fine on other computers? Here's my manifest (very simple app with one class Try in package main) Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: main.Try

Comment: You need to copy any jars referred to in the Class-Path: line too.

Comment: but as You can see, there are no additional JARs in the ClassPath (there's only a dot). App is very simple - one class inheriting from JFrame with one JButton, no additional code.

Comment: A dot is sufficient, if you reference classes not enclosed in the jar.  Try running "java -jar my.jar" in CMD.EXE and report the stack trace back from the machine that doesn't work.

Comment: I got the "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" exception. I installed newest JDK and now it's working. Many thanks.

Comment: Consider compiling with an older JDK to avoid this happening for others.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the jar in the classpath, like this:

```
java -classpath "C:\somepath\myapp.jar" mypackage.MyClass
```

Comment: As I wrote, that computer had no problems with running jars, but generated by Netbeans, so I guess the problem is not connected with classpath.

Comment: @user1091733 But classpath is not specific to a computer. It's specific to every single execution of java. Maybe the problem is not in the classpath, but we cannot take your word for it if you want us to solve your problem.