# Jar "Could not find main class" on SOME computers

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have a runnable JAR file that I created. It works on my computer just fine. It works on another persons computer just fine. Then, the third person tried it on their computer and received the error "Could not find the main class". The file was accessed from the same location all three times (on the network).

Where could my mistake be? Could it be the Java version on the third computer?

Comment: When this happened to [this other person asking the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165058/could-not-find-the-main-class-error), it was down to the JVM on the computer where it didn't work being older than the one on the computers where it did, sufficiently so that the main class was using the newer class format and couldn't be read by the old JVM. I think the last time binary imcompatibilities were introduced was Java 6, though, which is a while ago. Could they have a Java 5 JVM?

Comment: The computer with the issues was running Java 6. My computer is running 7 and I'm not sure about the second computer but I would guess 7 there as well. I'll see if he has time for an update to retry. Thanks for the input.